# EditorForModel and DisplayForModel don't work on Expando objects

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, expando

Or at least, they don't do what I was expecting.  My Action method looks like this:

```
    Function Test() As ActionResult
        Dim model As Object = New ExpandoObject()
        model.FieldA = 123
        model.FieldB = "This is a string"
        model.FieldC = DateTime.Now

        Return View(model)
    End Function
```

and the view looks like this:

```
@ModelType Object
@Html.DisplayForModel
```

I was expecting it to produce the same thing you'd get if the model were a real object with those fields, but instead I get this:

```
[FieldA, 123][FieldB, This is a string][FieldC, 3/29/2012 12:10:24 PM]
```

EditorForModel does the exact same thing.  Is this the correct behavior, and what's the best way to implement the behavior that I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is the correct behavior. Default metadata provider (DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider) uses reflection to get model information and that is the reason you get this result.

I would suggest to create a custom metadata provider that will work correctly with dynamics. Try to inherit from this class - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.dataannotationsmodelmetadataprovider.aspx.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm glad it's not just me.  But why doesn't the default provider handle dynamics in what seems like the obviously correct way?

Comment: I guess because nobody has expected it to be thrown at dynamic objects:-)